# How to setup ipython profile-specific extensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I would like to setup IPython profiles so that each profile has its own `extensions` folder with extension .py files. However, I can't seem to setup the path: it only takes outer extensions folder into account.

I'm running IPython version 7.5.0.
I have tried adding the folders to path manually in `ipython_config.py` file:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    "import os,sys;sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'extensions'))"]
```

I expected for given solution to solve my problem although that doesn't seem to be the case.